# batch rename of files in a specific dir

Tags: batch, rename

I need to create a .bat file that would remove the first 11 characters from pdf files in a specific dir. Can you please help? This should be easy for a coder, I think. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in powershell:

```
Get-ChildItem "Filepath" -Filter *.pdf | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name.ToString().Substring(11)}
```

- List all iles in "Filepath" and filter all PDF files with a wildcard.
- Pipe all files to `Rename-Item`.
- Take the characters after first 11 characters in the new file name.
- Save the script as a `.PS1` file using Windows PowerShell ISE If you wish to re-use it.

Comment: Thanks, I saved this in a .bat file in the same dir where the pdf files are stored, I ran it and nothing happens. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes. `.bat` files are for Command-Line interpretation, not PowerShell. You need to save it as a PowerShell `.ps1` file. I've updated the answer and up-voted it.

Comment: Thank you @spikey_richie for updating the answer.

Comment: File renamed to .ps1 and saved in the same dir as the pdf file, I ran it, nothing happens.

Comment: Replace "Filepath" with the path where pdf files are

Comment: Sorry to nag again, this is the complete string, again, no result :(
Get-ChildItem "D:\Dropbox\gbmolina\Embajada\bta" -Filter *.pdf | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name.ToString().Substring(11)}

Comment: I cannot understand why this isn't working for you. I have tested this in my own computer. It worked perfectly, I am suggesting you another thing, run this from powershell console **and replace "filepath" with the path where the pdf files are**

Comment: YES, it worked, but opening first the powershell console and pasting the command, the right button-run with powershell does not work for me in Win 7, interesting. Alas, it doesn´t make sense to use it this way, because it is easier to rename the two files every day by hand. Anyway, thanks a lot.

Comment: If the code worked please click the large check mark, welcome!

Comment: Please don't answer off topic questions, as it only encourages more users to ask them.

Comment: Ok @DavidPostill remember your suggestion